# Recursion limit?

Tags: matlab, recursion, limit

When I run my code on my laptop it runs without error,but when I run it from an old computer it throws me the error:

> Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.  Error in coder.allowpcode

I need to run my code from the old computer.I set also the recursion limit to a bigger value but my MATLAB program crash.

Comment: Can you include the relevant code?

Comment: Is the amount of physical memory same on your laptop the your old computer

Answer (score 2):

A 500 recursion is quite big, are you sure the code is good? Or are you recurring too often?

---

Assuming you code is good:

Your Matlab program crashes because you are causing a [`Stackoverflow`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) (yeah that's why this site has that name and that logo!).

The Stack memory in a computer is a memory that saves a link to "where the function has been called". Nowadays, modern computers have a decent Stack memory, but old ones didn't. If you overflow that memory, when the execution of a code is "finishing" and getting out the functions to the parent function, eventually it won't know where to go (because there was no enough space in the Stack memory). This will cause a crash of your system (or Matlab).

There is nothing you can do about this (if your code is correct). Basically do not use big recursion in old computers.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I manage to install the program that I need to work on a newer computer and there is no problem with the recursion limit.But I'm facing with an error for weeks and nobody answers to me on NI forum.I'm working with AWR-vss program,and I'm using the MATLAB block,and when I run the whole project it gives me the error: Failed to read MATLAB matrix out.I don't know what to do anymore.I will be grateful if you could give some ideas.